# Computing matrix representation of polynomial linear transform

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I am having trouble computing the matrixrepresentation of the following transform:
$$
L: P2 (R)\longrightarrow P2 (R)
$$
with

$$
L(\alpha+\beta x)=(3\alpha+2\beta)+(\alpha+2\beta)x
$$
I am using the base $V=(1,x)$ to compute $A=V[L]V$, but I think I am doing something wrong, hope you can give some advice. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's recall the definition of matrix representation

> If $T\colon V\to W$ is a linear map and $[v_1,\ldots,v_n]$ and $[w_1,\ldots,w_m]$ are ordered bases of $V$ and $W$, respectively, then the matrix of $T$ with respect to those bases is the $m\times n$ matrix $[T]=[t_{ij}]_{\substack{i=1,\ldots,m\\j=1,\ldots,n}}$ such that "$t_{ij}$ is the $i$-th coordinate of the $j$-th image $T(v_j)$; i.e., it satisfies $T(v_j)=\sum_i t_{ij}w_i$ for all $j$.

Ok. In the case given, we have $V=W=P_2(\mathbb{R})$, the space of polynomials of degree at most $1$. The bases on both the domain and the range are $[1,x]$. The spaces have degree $2$, so the matrix of the linear map given will be $2\times 2$.

Let $[L]=\begin{bmatrix}\ell_{11}&\ell_{12}\\\ell_{21}&\ell_{22}\end{bmatrix}$ be the matrix of $L$ in this basis. By the definition above, we have
$$\ell_{11}\cdot 1+\ell_{21}\cdot x=T(1)=T(1+0x)=3+x$$
so $\ell_{11}=3$ and $\ell_{21}=1$. A similar argument (left to you) shows that $\ell_{12}=\ell_{22}=2$.

Comment: Thank you for the help!